# Where I can find the source code of pdflatex.exe?

Tags: pdftex, sourcecode

Where I can find the source code of pdflatex.exe?

### Edit 1

This is quoted from the link given by @TH.

> pdfTeX is built on top of TeX, written by Donald Knuth cum suis (Liang and
>   so), and eTeX, written by Peter Breitenlohner cum suis; part of the
>   paragraph optimization is inspired by the work of Hermann Zapf.

Does it imply that the source code of `pdflatex.exe` will invoke `TeX` and `eTeX` ?

Comment: Good question: does pdf(la)tex always imply eTeX?

Comment: @Martin: pdfTeX contains the e-TeX extensions. See the introduction to the pdfTeX manual.

Comment: Better answers on this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385380/where-is-source-code-of-tex-luatex-pdftex/48

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>On CTAN. http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/pdftex/</s>

Links to the source code repository can be found on [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex/).

**Edit:**
To answer your follow up question, `pdflatex` does not invoke `tex` or `etex`. Rather, pdfTeX implements the *ε*-TeX extensions.

Comment: @TH. : thanks. By the way what is the difference between `pdftex.exe` and `pdflatex.exe` ? Please see my update also.

Comment: @xport `pdflatex` is a shortcut for `pdftex -fmt=pdflatex`. See `pdftex -help`.

Comment: @Andrey: Oh, `pdflatex.exe` = `pdftex.exe -fmt=pdflatex`. Unbelievable.

Comment: @xport: There are four ways to choose a format: the (base) name of the binary (e.g., `pdflatex`), via &format (e.g., `pdftex &pdflatex`, via `-fmt` (e.g., `pdftex -fmt pdflatex`), and via the first line of the input file (e.g., `%&pdflatex`).

Comment: @TH. : So the definition of `pdflatex` must exist first because it will be used by `pdftex`. It does not make sense actually. In my mental model, `pdftex` is more mature than `pdflatex`.

Comment: @xport: I don't know what you mean. `pdflatex` is just a format. In TeX Live, it lives in `.../texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`. `pdftex` is the name of the pdfTeX binary as well as the name of the format (`pdftex.fmt`) that is essentially the plain format but with pdfTeX extensions and pdf output. `latex` is just a format.

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: The source is more specifically available at https://tug.org/svn/pdftex/branches/stable/