# XeTeX source code

Tags: xetex, source

There has already been a question on [where to find the source code for `pdfTeX`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13016/2707).  The answer <s>is that it can be found on CTAN, [in the systems directory](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/pdftex)</s>. Update from 2023: [on tug.org](https://www.tug.org/svn/pdftex/).

Unfortunately, the source code for XeTeX is not there.  Where can I find the source code for XeTeX?

It would be interesting to provide links to the source codes of all major engines in the answer, to make it easier to access them.

Comment: @PauloCereda Please post this (and preferably links to the LuaTeX and pdfTeX source codes too, even if the latter is a bit redundant with my question) as an answer.

Comment: related: [historical versions of packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31886)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## `pdfTeX`

Source code: [[image: Source code] `https://www.tug.org/svn/pdftex/`](https://www.tug.org/svn/pdftex/)

## `XeTeX`

Homepage: [[image: Homepage] `https://xetex.sourceforge.net/`](https://xetex.sourceforge.net/)

Source code: [[image: Download] `https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/`](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/code/)

## `LuaTeX`

Homepage: [[image: Homepage] `http://luatex.org/`](http://luatex.org/)

Source code: [[image: Download] `https://gitlab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/texlive/luatex`](https://gitlab.lisn.upsaclay.fr/texlive/luatex) ([mirror](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source))

<sub>Friends, feel free to add more links if necessary.</sub>